# SharePoint bilingual site best practices

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have planned a bilingual site, based on SharePoint 2013 platform.
Can you tell me what are the good practices for this?
My client does not want to use third-party tool.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the good article you can refer: [SharePoint 2013 Variations](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_quick_reads/archive/2013/08/12/sharepoint-2013-variations-creating-site-and-variation-labels.aspx).

It is in-built SharePoint feature that you can use to achieve multilingual SharePoint site.

Also refer this: [Overview of SharePoint 2013 Multilingual Features](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2013/08/05/overview-of-sharepoint-2013-multilingual-features.aspx)

If you are thinking to implement this for SharePoint Online, read this article: [How to: set up multilingual intranet sites in SharePoint Online](http://www.sharemuch.com/2014/08/08/how-to-set-up-multilingual-intranet-sites-in-sharepoint-online/)

Note that all of the above article shares the how to achieve the bilingual site and it is not any third party tool.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's interesting : I'll watch these documents thank you for that. I forgot to clear : the problem is that in this application, we will also do a lot of custom code. Create a site template that will be deployed via wsp . This changes some things ?

Comment: Well, I haven't tried it but I think there will be no change in that.